# Woocommerce get_term_by() in transition_post_status hook doesn't works

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

Im having this code

```
$concours_termine_cat = get_term_by('slug' , 'concours-termine' , 'product_cat');
```

get_term_by is returning false, after debugging the get_term_by function

```
taxonomy_exists( 'product_cat');
```

is returning false.

So I checked in taxonomy_exists function and looks like into `$wp_taxonomies` product_cat doesn't exist at this time of execution.

I call this hook like this `add_action('transition_post_status' , 'vince_function_post_update' , 10 , 3);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why Woocommerce wasn't load at this time but I solve my issue adding this code :

```
if (! taxonomy_exists(  'product_cat' ) && class_exists('WC_Post_Types') ) {
    // Dans le cas ou la taxonomies n'est pas register
    WC_Post_Types::register_taxonomies();
}
```